# Limit of energy?

Tags: physics

What if there is any real limit of energy that can ever be accumulated in the gravitational field?

Described as: E(max) = m(max) * c^2

So... If some black hole reached that limit, (I would expect) the energy from inside the black hole could leak outside to the universe.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy SE! Your question doesn't seem to be about Philosophy, it may be better suited to https://physics.stackexchange.com/. If there is a philosophy question in here try to reformulate...

Comment: In the Physics thread I was told it's off-topic there :(

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit to the size of a black hole, and no way for any of its contents to "leak" out of it.

Comment: It is, and my answer is a simplified take on the physics. In my experience on the physics stack exchange, a question worded as this one is will get booted for lack of prior research, outside mainstream physics, or unclear what you're asking.

Comment: the pursuit of knowledge is the asking of many questions. good luck on your quest. -NN